# Apache spdy is on, passed spdycheck but browser still cannot use spdy

Tags: apache-2.4, spdy

After install mod_spdy, switch to mode ssl_with_npn and test with spdytest I see everything is working well:
https://spdycheck.org/#chuongduong.net

But when start with firefox, the spdy check plugins show my connection is not using spdy.

When use chrome, it also doesn't list my site in the http2 listing.

When force chrome top use spdy (run command chrome --use-spdy=ssl), when access to my website it say error:

```
This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

The webpage at https://www.chuongduong.net/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

I am using Apache/2.4.12, Centos 6

The spdy configuration is:

```
LoadModule spdy_module /etc/httpd/lib/libmod_spdy.so

SpdyEnabled on
SpdyMaxThreadsPerProcess 100
SpdyMaxStreamsPerConnection 100
```

The spdycheck report:

> Report Details
>   Network Server on 443
>
> Nice, this host has a network service listening on port 443! SPDY works over SSL/TLS which usually listens on port 443.
>   TLS v1.2 Connection Detected
>
> Good, this host is speaking SSL/TLS, specifically TLS v1.2. SPDY piggybacks on top of SSL/TLS, so a website needs SSL/TLS to use SPDY.
>   Valid X.509 Certificate
>
> This website is responding with a valid X.509 certificate. X.509 certificate errors can cause the browser to display warning messages and to stop speaking with the website, so using a valid certificate is an essential step to supporting SPDY.
>   ServerHello Contains NPN Extension
>
> Nice, this server including the NPN Extension during the SSL/TLS handshake. The NPN Extension is an additional part of the SSL/TLS ServerHello message which allows the web server to tell browser it supports additional protocols, like SPDY.
>   Success! SPDY is Enabled!
>
> Hurray, this website is using SPDY! The following protocols are supported:
>
> ```
> spdy/3
> spdy/2
> http/1.1
> x-mod-spdy/0.9.4.1-3c81dee
> ```
>
> SPDY Protocol Support Update-To-Date
>
> This website supports the latest version of SPDY, which is spdy/3.
>   HTTP Fallback Detected
>
> This website is using SPDY, but it also supports traditional HTTP over SSL. This ensures that older web browsers can still access this site using HTTP
>   HTTP Redirects to SPDY
>
> Pretty Sexy! Accessing this website via HTTP automatically redirects the user to access the website via SSL/TLS and SPDY. This means all of website's visitors that can browse the site with SPDY, do browse the site using SPDY.
>
> Strict-Transport-Security Supported
>
> Excellent! This website is using HSTS, also known as Strict Transport Security. This tells the browser to always use SSL when talking to this website, allows more of your visitors the opportunity to both be secure and to use SPDY. The server is sending the header Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload which tells the web browser to always use SSL to access this website for the next 730 days.